# Jasmine working with namespaces

Tags: javascript, namespaces, jasmine

I have the following problem. I am trying to test one JS file, which contains a lot of functions. All of them have namespace like
x.y.z.function(), but in some of them i have to call function, which is in another file and have namespace x.y.h.function(). The problem is that when i make the import scripts<> in the html, in correct order(checked it 100 times), at the end Jasmine says that the x.y.h is undefined, if i define it at the beggining, it says that such method doesn't exist. Looks like it just searching in the current file, not in all imported ones.

I also checked it with removing of all namespaces- it worked perfectly. The problem is that i can't remove the namespaces from everywhere.

See the example:

```
    describe("Test core functionality", function () {
it("get_screen_vm",function(){
expect(get_screen("screen_24_34")).not.toBeDefined();
});
```

The inspected method

```
a.b.c.e.get_screen_vm = function ( unique_s_id ) {

var screen_win = a.b.c.d.get_screen_window_by_unique_id(unique_s_id);

return ( screen_win != undefined ) ? screen_win.values_manager : undefined;
};
```

The HTML

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-core/boot/boot.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/mousetrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="gui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/core_specs.js"></script>
```

Exactly now it gives me:

```
Error   1   Test 'Test core functionality:screen_vm' failed
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.b.c.d.get_screen_window_by_unique_id') in file:///C:/Users/kiril.mladenov/Documents/Aptana%20Studio%203%20Workspace/jasmine/core.js (line 608)
        at file:///C:/Users/kiril.mladenov/Documents/Aptana%20Studio%203%20Workspace/jasmine/ut3_core.js:608
        at file:///C:/Users/kiril.mladenov/Documents/Aptana%20Studio%203%20Workspace/jasmine/spec/ut3_core_specs.js:21
        at attemptSync (file:///C:/Users/kiril.mladenov/AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/o3su1t3v.wpt/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1510)
        at file:///C:/Users/kiril.mladenov/AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/o3su1t3v.wpt/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1498
        at file:///C:/Users/kiril.mladenov/AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/o3su1t3v.wpt/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1485
in C:\Users\kiril.mladenov\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jasmine\spec\ut3_core_specs.js (line 20) C:\Users\kiril.mladenov\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jasmine\spec\core_specs.js  20
```

If someone had this problem before, i will be very thankful.

Kiril

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes, it just have to be defined in the beggining-

a.b.c.d = {};